# Prefix-Free vs Uniquely Decodable Codes

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

It has been proved on the Cover-Thomas book that for a set of uniquely decodable codes with lengths $\{l_i\}$ (finite or infinite) that satisfies the Kraft-McMillan inequality, $\sum_i 2^{-l_i}\le 1$,  we can construct an instantaneous code with the same code-word lengths, which can be expressed as nodes on a tree graph.

I'm a bit confused about a (counter)example: fixed-length code (for example, all binary codes with length 10, not more/less, of which there are $2^{10}=1024$ of them; they should be uniquely decodable but not prefix-free). It obviously satisfies the Kraft-McMillan inequality: the sum $\sum 2^{-10}=2^{10}\cdot2^{-10}=1$. Henceforth, we should be able to construct an instantaneous code with the same code-word length. However, the lengths are uniformly l=10; while for instantaneous codes, there is at most 1 code per length (which, on the tree graph, means that no code-word is an ancestor of any other code words). We cannot assign codes with the same length to nodes of different depths. There seems to be a contradiction.

I'm pretty sure that I misunderstood something. I would really appreciate it if you could let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Prefix-free means that no codeword is a prefix of another codeword.  This is clearly true of the code you describe.  The code is instantaneous.  Every $10$ bits you have a codeword and decode it.  I don't know why you say that in an instantaneous code, all codewords are or different lengths.  Huffman codes are instantaneous, but you can have multiple codewords of a given length.  $0,10,11$ is an instantaneous code with two codewords of length $2$.

Answer (score 1):

> fixed-length codes ... should be uniquely decodable but not prefix-free

This is false. A (non singular) fixed-length code is trivially prefix-free, because a codeword cannot be a prefix of another codeword.

> while for instantaneous codes, there is at most 1 code per length

Again, false.

An instantaneous codes correspond to a rooted tree where the codewords correspond to leaves (i.e., non internal nodes). Both codes ([source](https://www.icg.isy.liu.se/courses/tsbk02/material/instantaneous.pdf)) here are instantaneous

[image]